# Loop to select one distinced row from entire table ordered and grouped by a relation

Tags: php, mysql, sql, group-by

In my query here

```
SELECT a.FirstName, a.LastName, a.Country, SUM(b.Scores) AS Score FROM names a LEFT JOIN scores b ON a.id = b.id WERE id = :id GROUP BY a.FirstName ORDER BY Score ASC
```

Now what i'm trying to do is to get a `Distinct` country div, Contains all the `First/LastNames` ordered by their `Score` Like the following

```
[id  --  FirstName  -- LastName  --  Country]
[1   --   FName1    --  LName1   --    CO1  ]
[2   --   FName2    --  LName2   --    CO1  ]
[3   --   FName3    --  LName3   --    CO2  ]
[4   --   FName4    --  LName4   --    CO3  ]
```

to get it like this

```
CO1: (FName1-LName1,FName2-LName2)
CO2: (FName3-LName3)
CO3: (FName4-LName4)
```

So i used this loop to get it working.

```
$pre = null;
echo "<div>";
$end = "";
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    $FName = $row['FirstName'];
    $LName = $row['LastName'];
    $Country = $row['Country'];

    if ($Country != $pre) {
        echo $end;
        echo "<div id='$Country'>$Country:";
        echo "<div class='objects'>";
    }
    $end = "</div></div>";
    $pre = $Country;
    echo "<div>($FName - $LName)</div>";
}
echo $end;
```

It works OK for me, But When i refresh, I get the `CO1` repeated again, And if refershed again, It disappears, And again and again, If i removed the `Scores` part, It works perfectly, But with it It keeps repeating.

Comment: You never do anything with `$pre` nor `$end`.

Comment: @trincot solved that in the code now, I use to to prevent repeating the $country again for each row.

Comment: `$stmt->fetch()` what library is that? mysqli or PDO?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel PDO

Comment: Have a look at [`fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP)`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php). `a.Country` should be selected as first column.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Can't really figure out how to use it in the loop.

Comment: @AXAI You don't need a loop to fetch the data if you use `fetchAll()`. Es you may guess - it fatches **all** rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make things easier if you first create the grouped structure in an array, like this:

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    $countries[$row['Country']][] = $row;
}
```

Now `$countries` will have one entry per country, which in turn will have the array of related rows. You can then produce the HTML as follows:

```
foreach ($countries as $country => $rows) {
    echo "<div id='$country'>$country\n";
    echo "  <div class='objects'>\n";
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        echo "    <div>({$row['FirstName']} - {$row['LastName']})</div>\n";
    }
    echo "  </div>\n</div>\n";
}
```

See it run on [eval.in](https://eval.in/844739).

Comment: That really easier to use, But is it possible to use SQL instead of PHP in my code? Since SQL would be faster, Using `GROUP_CONCAT` and so on.

Comment: An SQL `select` does not generate a nested structure, just rows. What you do here is really formatting (to nested HTML elements), and that is not the job (nor the strength) of SQL. Of course, it would be possible, but in my opinion not best practice.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `GROUP BY` correctly.

Try this:

```
GROUP BY a.FirstName, a.LastName, a.Country
```

That should ensure you get the country values.

Comment: Still repeats and removed with each refresh the first selected country.

Comment: Using GROUP BY `a.Country` only solves the repetation, But gets only one row.

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the data in a hierarchical structured array using [`PDO::fetchAll()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) with the `PDO::FETCH_GROUP` mode.

```
$data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP|PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

This will group your data by the first selected column. So you should select the `Country` column as the first one. The array should the look like the following:

```
$data = [
    'CO1' => [
        ['FistName' => 'FName1', 'LastName' => 'LName1', 'Score' => '1'],
        ['FistName' => 'FName2', 'LastName' => 'LName2', 'Score' => '2']
    ],
    'CO2' => [
        ['FistName' => 'FName3', 'LastName' => 'LName3', 'Score' => '3']
    ],
    'CO3' => [
        ['FistName' => 'FName4', 'LastName' => 'LName4', 'Score' => '4']
    ]
];
```

Now you can use a nested `foreach` loop to print your data.